# Desktop PC power supplies - will a fancy one save power (while powering same hardware components)?

Tags: power-supply, power-management, desktop-computer

Say I put a cheap power supply into a PC, could I save electricity costs by replacing it with some kind of fancy PSU (that's "more efficient" or has some kind of intelligent power management)?

I know some (more expensive) desktop PC power supply units can be more reliable, quieter, or have more max watts than others.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, a better PSU can increase efficiency and reduce cost of operation.  High quality PSUs have more sophisticated electronics for greater efficiency.  See the [Wikipedia article on 80 PLUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_PLUS), a certification program for high-efficiency PSUs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as previously answered. Also, never put a cheap power supply in a PC - it will die in a year or so. Pay about ~ $100 for 500W and look for statements like "high quality Japanese capacitors".

Comment: Very true - quality Japanese capacitors have greater reliability as well as higher temperature limits.